# Multi-Domain Stores, One Secure Domain for Checkout, good practise?

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore, ssl

So this is my lay-out:

Multi-stores on different domains:

domain.com
domain.fr
domain.es
domain.pt

My hosting doesn't have multidomain SSL licence so I can only use the SSL on one domain.

since the base domain is always the same and only the extension changes, I was thinking of using secure.domain.com for secure checkout.

From what I have ready this is easily done on magento, but I have some questions:

1. Is it a good practise to do this?
2. The user won't see "warnings" like "You are changing website be careful", etc?
3. I only want to use secure domain on check-out, no need to do it on login/account, can this be done?
4. Will it work even if the domain.com store doesn't have the same products has the other stores?

Thank you!

Tiago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, it is fine to use a "shared" SSL domain for the secure portion in Magento in checkout. There are no technical issues with this. It may not be ideal, as it complicates tracking with things like Google Analytics, but there are no issues with using it in this manner.
2. The user will not see any warnings if all items (images, css, js) on the secure pages are called securely. There are no issues with this.
3. Yes, you can remove the security from other sections. In app/code/core/Mage, you'll find config.xml files that set the secure_url for various functions. You can modify these to remove the "" section to disable SSL for these features. The ones that use this are:

   Centinel/etc/config.xml
   Checkout/etc/config.xml
   Customer/etc/config.xml
   Downloadable/etc/config.xml
   Install/etc/config.xml
   Newsletter/etc/config.xml
   Ogone/etc/config.xml
   Paygate/etc/config.xml
   Paypal/etc/config.xml
   PaypalUk/etc/config.xml
   Persistent/etc/config.xml
   Review/etc/config.xml
   Rss/etc/config.xml
   Sales/etc/config.xml
   Tag/etc/config.xml
   Wishlist/etc/config.xml
4. I don't see any issues with the stores having different products.